# Recommended Themes for a Developer-related Topics Blog?

Tags: themes

*(**Moderator's note:** Was previously titled: "What is the best theme used for a developer like me?")*

I'm a developer and write a blog to share my knowledge with readers. I'm looking for a theme which is best suited with me but not sure which ones. Please share if you've ever visited a nice theme.

Comment: Hi *@Nam Gi VU* - These types of questions are the kind that we try to avoid here because they have no definitive answer and encourage *"religious"* debates, which goes against the ideal for StackExchange. But rather than delete I'll mark as a community wiki so that it can be used to gather a list of solutions. If other moderators feel the same then we may delete the question, especially if you've not gotten (m)any answers.

Comment: It's quite scary :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Related Questions

As this is a community wiki question, I'll start to link related questions in the hope of use. Not a real answer so far but probably of help. Feel free to extend:

- [What theme is good for posting code?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/what-theme-is-good-for-posting-code)